# Comparing two matrix (A & B) and output a new matrix C with cij = min(aij, bij)

Tags: r

The title is fairly clear, but I'm trying to take two matrices, A and B, and output a matrix C that has the minimum elements from the two matrices.

cij = min(aij, bij)

This is how I'm considering doing it this way:

```
C <- matrix(ncol = ncol(A), nrow = nrow(A), 0)
for (i in 1:ncol(C)) {
    Y <- rbind(A[i,], B[i,])
    C[i,] <- apply(Y, 2, min)
}
```

However, I was hoping this could be vectorized but I can't think how to do it. I haven't found anything so if anyone has any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

See `?pmin` (parallel minimum):

```
R> A <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
R> B <- matrix(c(5, 1, 1, 6), 2, 2)
R> A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
R> B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    1
[2,]    1    6
R> pmin(A, B)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    4
```

Comment: @rcs but here you suppose the mtarix have the same length.

Comment: both matrices have to have the same dimension since the OP wrote `cij = min(aij, bij)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
C <- A
C[A>B] <- B[A>B]
```

This is less straightforward but will work. Demonstration:

```
> A <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
> B <- matrix(c(5, 1, 1, 6), 2, 2)
> C <- A
> C[A>B] <- B[A>B]
> 
> A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
> B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    1
[2,]    1    6
> C
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    4
```